# Significance of AsEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, asenumerable

```
var query = 
    from dt1 in dtStudent.AsEnumerable()
    join dt2 in dtMarks.AsEnumerable()
        on dt1.Field<int>("StudentID")
        equals dt2.Field<int>("StudentID")
    select new StudentMark
    {
        StudentName = dt1.Field<string>("StudentName"),
        Mark = dt2.Field<int>("Mark")
    };
```

In the above coding, what is the significance of `AsEnumerable`? if the `AsEnumerable` doesn't exist in .NET Framework, then what would be the approach of developers to perform the above the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm interpreting it correctly, it's calling [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx). Without that (or something similar), you can't use LINQ to Objects as `DataTable` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only `IEnumerable`.

Note that an alternative would be to use `Cast<DataRow>`, but that would be subtly different as that would use the `DataTable`'s `GetEnumerator` directly within `Cast`, whereas I believe [`EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918783.aspx) does slightly more funky things with the data table. It's unlikely to show up any real changes, except possibly a slight performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

The `.AsEnumerable()` extension is just short-hand for casting something that implements `IEnumerable<T>` to be `IEnumerable<T>`

So, if `xs` is `int[]`, you can call `xs.AsEnumerable()` instead of `(xs as IEnumerable<int>)`. It uses type inference to avoid needing to explicitly keying the type of `xs`.

Here's the code extracted by Reflector.NET:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source;
}
```

But in this case I think I have to agree with Jon. It's probably from the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly.